# How to add dollar sign before column value and after adding the particular column in pandas python

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I want to add the dollar sign before the column values after sum that values, I have given some sample format below:

```
item_orders = [{'price':'$20','quantity':'2','order_item':'pizza','total_amount':'$40'},
              {'price':'$20','quantity':'1','order_item':'potato fry','total_amount':'$20'} ]
```

**code **

```
available_cart_item = pd.DataFrame(item_orders)
available_cart_item.loc['Total'] = pd.Series(available_cart_item['total_amount'].sum(), index=['total_amount']) 
print(available_cart_item)
```

**got something like this**

[image: below code result image]

I want something like this

[image: Requied format using pandas]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If possible better is use numeric values without `$` for simplier procesessing in pandas.

```
available_cart_item['total_amount'] = available_cart_item['total_amount'].str.strip('$')
```

Remove `$` by [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html), convert to `integer`s and `sum`. Last add `$` by `f-string`s.

```
item_orders = [{'price':'$20','quantity':'2','order_item':'pizza','total_amount':'$40'},
              {'price':'$20','quantity':'1','order_item':'potato fry','total_amount':'$20'} ]

available_cart_item = pd.DataFrame(item_orders)

total = available_cart_item['total_amount'].str.strip('$').astype(int).sum()
#pandas 3.6+
available_cart_item.loc['Total', 'total_amount'] = f'${total}'
#pandas below 3.6
#available_cart_item.loc['Total', 'total_amount'] = '${}'.format(total)
available_cart_item = available_cart_item.fillna('')
print (available_cart_item)
       order_item price quantity total_amount
0           pizza   $20        2          $40
1      potato fry   $20        1          $20
Total                                     $60
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the $, your DataFrame is treating the price and total_amount columns as strings.

You can convert them to numerical values by stripping the '$', and then you can sum the values in the column as you would expect.

If you would like to display the total amounts in the DataFrame with a $ you can use pandas styling (see documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html))

```
from IPython.display import display

item_orders = [{'price':'$20','quantity':'2','order_item':'pizza','total_amount':'$40'},
               {'price':'$20','quantity':'1','order_item':'potato fry','total_amount':'$20'}]

available_cart_item = pd.DataFrame(item_orders)

# convert from strings to float values
available_cart_item['quantity'] = available_cart_item['quantity'].astype(int)
available_cart_item['total_amount'] = available_cart_item['total_amount'].str.strip('$').astype(float)
available_cart_item['price'] = available_cart_item['price'].str.strip('$').astype(float)

available_cart_item.loc['Total'] = pd.Series(available_cart_item['total_amount'].sum(), index=['total_amount']) .astype(float)
available_cart_item.fillna('', inplace=True)

# adds the $ through style formatting
formatters={'price': lambda x: '' if type(x)==str else '\u20B9{:.2f}'.format(x), 
            'total_amount': lambda x: '' if type(x)==str else '\u20B9{:.2f}'.format(x), 
            'Total': lambda x: '' if type(x)==str else '\u20B9{:.2f}'.format(x)}

display(available_cart_item.style.format(formatters))
```

Comment: thanks for your kind reply 
if I use rupee symbol how do I continue above step
# python interpret as rupee symbol
`symbol_str = "\u20B9" `
   `available_cart_item = pd.DataFrame(item_orders)
    available_cart_item['total_amount'] = available_cart_item['total_amount'].str.strip(symbol_str).astype(int)
    available_cart_item.loc['Total'] = pd.Series(available_cart_item['total_amount'].sum(), index=['total_amount'])
    available_cart_item.style.format({'total_amount': 'symbol_str{:.2f}', 'Total': 'symbol_str{:.2f}'})
    available_cart_item = available_cart_item.fillna('')`

Comment: Just replace the $ with \u20B9, like {'total_amount': '\u20B9{:.2f}', 'Total': '\u20B9{:.2f}'}

Comment: no, I'm not getting it

only strip value as shown as a result

Comment: kindly suggest me the better way to fix this issue

Comment: @jezrael I'm writing into the column.   after strip, I'm just writing over it like this   
` rupee_symbol = "\u20B9"`     
  `available_cart_item.loc['Total', 'total_amount'] = '{}{}'.format(rupee_symbol, total)`

Comment: @jezrael just use this format this will write before the column values
`available_cart_item.loc['Total', 'total_amount'] = '{}{}'.format(rupee_symbol, total)`

Comment: @hamsa - OK, so my solution working and nother not, then what was reason for another solution? Or my solution is wrong? What was reason for reaccepting? (It is up to you, what reason is accepting, but I am curious if something wrong with my solution.)

Comment: @jezrael your solution perfect for dollar sign but I want rupee symbol before the column value so, just modified the format for writing into column values

Comment: @Matt I just followed its working great to me
`rupee_symbol = "\u20B9"`
`available_cart_item.loc['Total', 'total_amount'] = '{}{}'.format(rupee_symbol, total)`